# VkSubpassDependency specification clarification

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to understand the specification of the VkSubpassDependency structure.

[Link to VkSubpassDependency structure is on the specification page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSubpassDependency.html)

The part that confuses me a lot is the relationship between (**srcSubpass**, **dstSubpass**) and (**srcStageMask**, **dstStageMask**).

The case where srcSubpass is equal to dstSubpass is the same as a pipeline barrier and doesn't raise any questions for me. However, other cases are quite questionnable.

The specification says:

> If *srcSubpass* is equal to *VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL*, the first synchronization scope includes commands that occur earlier in submission order than the vkCmdBeginRenderPass used to begin the render pass instance. Otherwise, the first set of commands includes all commands submitted as part of the subpass instance identified by *srcSubpass* and any load, store or multisample resolve operations on attachments used in *srcSubpass*. **In either case, the first synchronization scope is limited to operations on the pipeline stages determined by the source stage mask specified by *srcStageMask*.**

By using the definition of syncronisation scopes given by the specification in [synchronization-dependencies](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies) I interpret the specification this way:

- If **srcSubpass** and **dstSubpass** are equal to the same actual subpass numbers and **srcStageMask**, **dstStageMask** are equal to some Pipeline stage, for example VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT.

I interpret in this case that the dependency works in the following way: **srcSubpass** executes freely over the pipeline stages until it reaches the stage given in **srcStageMask** parameter and stalls until the **dstSubpass** reaches the stage described in **dstStageMask**.

- If **srcSubpass** is equal to **VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL**, **dstSubpass** is equal to the actual existing subpass number and **srcStageMask**, **dstStageMask** is equal to the same Pipeline stage.

In that case I am getting confused about determining the first syncronisation scope.

Because the **srcSubpass** is equal to **VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL** then the first synchronisation scope includes commands that occur earlier in the submission order than the vkCmdBeginRenderPass used
to begin the render pass instance as the specification says. Because the external commands may not have any interaction with the pipeline stages, it makes the interpretation of **srcStageMask** quite ambiguous. Because nothing relates to the pipeline stage may not be outside the render pass: Does the line from the specification: "In either case, the first synchronization scope is limited to operations on the pipeline stages determined by the source stage mask specified by srcStageMask." refers to the pipeline stages inside **dstSubpass** and that extends the first syncronistaion scope down to **srcStageMask** stage in **dstSubpass**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are largely answering your questions. I think the problem is you have the wrong intuition about pipeline stages.

Think about all the commands you have submitted to a queue. Each command is at any point  in some pipeline stage, and all commands proceed through the pipeline independently (I should say asynchronously). Think of the pipeline as a playing board, and think of the commands as pegs that go on that board. Everything else should start making sense with that new intuition.

A Pipeline Barrier\Subpass Dependency introduces a dependency. The effect is all the commands in the source scope have to finish at least the `srcStageMask` stage in their execution, before any of the commands in the destination scope are even allowed to start the `dstStageMask` stage of their execution.

---

`srcSubpass == dstSubpass` is a special case that does nothing but declare a subpass self-dependency. All it does is allow you to later use `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` inside that Subpass recording. That works mostly like a normal Pipeline Barrier, except it is limited to the commands inside that Subpass, and it is not allowed to change Image Layouts.

`srcSubpass < dstSubpass` case introduces a dependency between those two Subpasses. The commands recorded in the `srcSubpass` are the source scope, and the commands in `dstSubpass` are the destination scope. I.e. all commands in the source subpass must reach at least `srcStage`, before any of the commands in the destination subpass are  allowed to start the `dstStage` of their execution.

`VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` refers to the outside of the Render Pass Instance.

I.e. if `srcSubpass == VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`, then the source scope is all commands recorded before `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` and anything earlier in *submission order*. So, this Subpass Dependency would say all commands before the render pass instance have to reach at least their `srcStage` stage of execution, before any of the commands of the `dstSubpass` enter their `dstStage` stages.

If `dstSubpass == VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL` then the destination scope is all commands recorded after `vkCmdEndRenderPass` (and also later in *submission order*). So, this Subpass Dependency would say all commands recorded in the `srcSubpass` subpass have to reach at least their `srcStage` stage of execution, before any of the commands after the Render Pass Instance enter their `dstStage` stages of execution.

Comment: But in the case of srcSubpass == VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL, an externall commands (commands before vkCmdBeginRenderPass) may dosen't have pipeline stages at all.

Comment: For example (https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#swapchain-image-acquire-and-present) For introduced dependency srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT. In that example a prior external command which may execute this pipeline stage is not exists. In that case it is simple pipeline barrier with image layout transition even if srcSubpass == VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL. Syncronisation of vkAcquireNextImageKHR with the VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT stage of rendering subpass is achived with semaphore.

Comment: @YuriDolotkazin In that case the Subpass Dependency forms a [dependency chain](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-dependencies-chains) with the `pWaitDstStageMask`. If there are two sync primitives like this, they form a dependency chain acting like there is only one sync primitive doing both. There do not have to be any actual commands inbetween, and there does not have to be any "real" pipeline stage executed.